# Как перенести flex элемент на новую строку?

Tags: html, css

Нужно перенести на новую строку элемент `<div class="item">3</div>`

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  /*flex-wrap: wrap; Без использования этого параметра */
}
.item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  flex: auto;
}
.item:last-child {
  /* ? */
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: а чем `flex-wrap` не устраивает?

Comment: @ZxNuClear он действует для всех элементов и переносит их при разных размеров, нужно перенести только последний элемент

Comment: у вас div 1 и div 2 будут занимать всю ширину контейнера?

Answer (score 0):

Предположу, что 1й и 2й div-ы, даже имея разные размеры, должны занимать всю ширину контейнера. Тогда, все же с помощью `flex-wrap`, третий div можно переместить на новую строку, при этом он не обязательно должен быть во всю ширину контейнера. Возможно такой вариант вам подойдет

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.item:nth-child(1) {
  width: 35%;
}
.item:nth-child(2) {
  width: 65%;
}
.item:nth-child(3) {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```